# What is the equivalent of Parallel.Invoke in a .NET Core 3.1 app?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a service which acts as HTTP client, it suppose to communicate with hundreds of devices online, the purpose is to get data from the device and save it in the database, the above cycle should re-occur every 10 minutes.

The devices does not depend on each other, I can get the data in parallel from all of them so my only limitation is the machine running the code and the available resources.

I currently use `Parallel.Invoke()` method to execute the the data gathering but I'm not very satisfied with the time it takes to complete 1 cycle, I was hopping someone will know a better method included in .NET Core 3.1 for this type of work.

Here is my code:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

        // Get Relevant Gateways
        string GetRouters = "SELECT * FROM RouterModel;";
        var Routers = await dataAccess.LoadData<RouterModel, dynamic>(GetRouters, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("GalronDb"));

        string GetMeters = "SELECT * FROM PowerMeterModel;";
        var Meters = await dataAccess.LoadData<PowerMeterModel, dynamic>(GetMeters, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("GalronDb"));

        foreach (RouterModel Router in Routers)
        {
            if (Router.IsHavePowerMeters)
            {
                foreach (PowerMeterModel Meter in Meters.Where(x => x.IdGateway == Router.Id).ToList())
                {
                    if (Meter.IsActive)
                    {
                        actionList.Add(new Action(() =>{ GetNewReadings(Router, Meter);}));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Parallel.Invoke(actionList.ToArray());
        actionList.Clear();

        _logger.LogInformation("*************** Sync loop is finished ***************");

        await Task.Delay(10 * 1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try adding this line at the start of the program: `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);`, and see if it makes any difference? This is suggested as a debugging attempt, not as a fix.

Comment: The `Parallel` class has been designed for CPU bound parallelism not for I/O bound. `GetNewReadings` seems to me an I/O bound operation. For I/O bound operations `await Task.WhenAll(actionList.ToArray());` should be used.

Comment: @PeterCsala Using Task Factory and await all tasks gives me about the same performance. I think I should go for a diffrent approach by creating a worker for each device, thus, isolating the slow syncing device (due to low lantecity). Anyway, thank you for the insight, I will accept this answear

Comment: @TomBoudniatski: A task factory is essentially equivalent to `Parallel`. What you want is to make the I/O asynchronous (i.e., `GetNewReadings`), and *then* use `Task.WhenAll`. No task factory should be necessary.